# Is there similar replayWhenNoConsumers in ActiveMQ Artemis as in classic

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are currently migrating from ActiveMQ classic to Artemis. We can not find any similar as replayWhenNoConsumers in network of brokers in Artemis. Is there no need för this flag or have we missed something in reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration parameter directly equivalent to `replayWhenNoConsumers` in ActiveMQ Artemis due to architectural differences between it and ActiveMQ Classic.